# First element on Intent.ACTION_VIEW does not allow me to choose the application

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I have an `ArrayList` with an adapter that has a button which retrieves a PDF from a url. I am using `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and it works fine, except on the first element of the `ArrayList`, in which it does not allow me to choose the application to open the PDF, it just opens the url with `Google Chrome` application. If I choose the rest of the elements, I can choose between open the PDF with `Google Chrome` or `Adobe`.

Here is the fragment of code that I use to get the PDF:

```
final ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<>();
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(data,new MyAdapter.MyOnItemClickListener()
{
     @Override
     public void myOnItemClick(int button, int position) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));         
           startActivity(intent);
     }
}, getContext());
recView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

How can I force that all buttons let the user choose between both applications?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is just the first element of the `ArrayList` that doesn't give you options then I suggest you compare the URL with the ones that do.

Comment: @Abbas The URL is the same, just changes the last parameter of the url (to show the PDF related with each item). It is why I do not understand why it does not give me both options when I click on the first one element.

Comment: Works for me I used [this](http://cdrsee.org/jhp/pdf/workbook1_eng_ed2.pdf) to open and I get the correct options each time on every item.

Comment: @Abbas Please do not add links to your personal pdfs. Post some code if you think you can help me to get the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your concern but this is not my personal pdf. You can find it while searching on google. See my project on [github](https://github.com/abbasshah17/url-adobe-launcher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved it setting the intent as pdf with `setDataAndType` method. Now it let you choose the application that you will use in all the buttons of each element.

This is the snippet of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();                         
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
```